# How can I capture a dtmf code on for a call sent out of twilio?

Tags: twilio, dtmf

I send calls out by building an html file that contains twiml markup, and use the php lib to place the call to the outgoing number (see e.g.)

```
$tw_call = $twilio_client->calls->create(
        "+1".$recipient['address'], "+1".$org['twilio_number'], 
        array(
            'Url' => VOICE_CALL_LINK.'/'.$file, (this contains the SAY verbs and text)
            'Timeout' => '30',
            'StatusCallback' => CALLBACK_LINK.'/voice_call_handler.php',
            'StatusCallbackEvent' => array('initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'completed')
            )
```

I want to know if it is possible to record a dtmf code from the call recipient via the method I am using for placing the call?

Can an additional callback url be placed in the text file? If so how would I capture which call the was coming back?  Would the call sid be available to the possible callback url within the text file?

Ok I must be missing something.  I tried the following:

```
<Response>
    <Pause length='1'/>
    <Say voice='alice'>$intro</Say>
    <Pause length='1'/>
    <Say voice='alice'>$msg_body</Say>
    <Pause length='1'/>
    <Gather action='absolute html path' numDigits='1'>
        <Say Please respond by selecting 1 for I can come.  Select 2 for I cannot come.</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>";
```

I get back from Twilio "an application error has occurred".  If I remove the Gather tags and the Say tag within the Gather tags, I receive a perfect call.

Same error occurs if I leave the tags and remove the action and path.

Can you gather responses on outbound calls?  I ask because all twilio docs refer to inbound call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In order to capture DTMF tones from a call you can use the [`<Gather>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) verb. This would probably go in the file which contains your `<Say>` that you point to in the code above. [`<Say>` can be nested within `<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#nesting-rules) in order to allow you to ask the user for input and start taking it as soon as they start typing.

The TwiML might look like this:

```
<Response>
  <Gather action="/gather_result.php" numDigits="1">
    <Say>Welcome to the free beer hotline, dial 1 for free beer, dial 2 for other beverages.</Say>
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

Then, when the user dials the number (you can control how many numbers with the `numDigits` attribute) Twilio will make a request to the URL in the `action` attribute. Within that request will be a [`Digits` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action) which will contain the numbers the user pressed. The call SID would also be among the parameters.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Was this a stream of consciousness comment? :D Did you find the action attribute? It's like in my code example in the answer, it needs a URL.

Comment: Then what happened? If it's easier, you can update your question.

Comment: Updated my question.  The return key gets me in these comment blocks.

Comment: Thought that might be the case :D Can you check your [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger) and see what the errors that were reported when you added the Gather?

Comment: No errors were reported at all.  The most recent error or warning is from yesterday.

Comment: Can you email your account sid to me at philnash@twilio.com and I'll take a quick look.

Comment: Went and looked at the call logs.  Calls show as being completed, however they are highlighted in red.  Not sure what that means.

Comment: email sent as requested

Comment: Didn't spot it before, but your `<Say>` in the `<Gather>` has an incomplete tag. It's `<Say Please...`. That's the error!

Comment: Thanks Phil!  Seven hours of looking at code and you go blind to the obvious!

Comment: I know exactly what you mean :D

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue where Gather TwiML was not capturing the user dtmf input from a call sent out of twilio. For some reasons, it failed to capture my input digit. I did press 1#, but the voice message keep playing and repeating the same message. Sometimes it works and twilio able to get the digit that I inputted, but more than 80% of the times I tried, it failed to capture the inputted digit. Below is the TwiML in node js looks like:

```
var promise = new Parse.Promise();

twilioClient.calls.create({
    to: phoneNumber,
    from:'+6598124124',
    url: hosturl + '/gather_user_dial',
    body: callParam,
    statusCallback: hosturl + '/callback_user',
    statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
    statusCallbackEvent: ["completed", "busy", "no-answer", "canceled", "failed"]
}).then(function(call) {
    if (res) res.success(call);
    promise.resolve(call);
}, function(error) {
    console.error('Call failed!  Reason: ' + error.message);
    if (res) res.error(error);
    promise.reject(error);
});
```

```
app.post('/gather_user_dial', (request, response) => {
  const twiml = new VoiceResponse();

  const gather = twiml.gather({
    numDigits: 1,
    timeout: 5,
    actionOnEmptyResult: true,
    action: '/gather',
  });
  gather.say('You are receiving a call from company A because you press the emergency button. Press 1 if you are okay or Press 9 if you need help, followed by the pound sign.');

  twiml.redirect('/gather_user_dial');
  response.type('text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());
});

app.post('/gather', (request, response) => {
  const twiml = new VoiceResponse();
  if (request.body.Digits) {
    switch (request.body.Digits) {
      case '1':
        twiml.say('User has been notified!');
        userPressOne(request.body.Called);
        break;
      case '9':
        twiml.say('User has been notified!');
        userPressNine(request.body.Called);
        break;
      default:
        twiml.say("Sorry, I don't understand that choice.").pause();
        twiml.redirect('/gather_user_dial');
        break;
    }
  } else {
      twiml.redirect('/gather_user_dial');
  }
  response.type('text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());
});
```